# Jquery-method in .NET not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net, visual-studio-2008

I'm running Visual Studio 2008 and .NET 3.5

I created a javascript method (window.unbeforeload) with javascript to give users a message when trying to exit the site. Unfortunatly, the same message is displayed every time a user clicks a link that's not redirecting outside of the site.

Solution: to let jquery handle all link-clicks inside the site. But this isn't working.

```
 <asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="HTML/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">    
     $(document).live('click',function() {
         $("a").click(function() {
             alert("Hello world!");
         });
     });                                       
    </script>
```

//lots of other functions

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          return "REALLY?"
      }
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

Here I tried making any click on a link inside the site create an alert, to no success.

**How to go about making Jquery work in my application?**

Sideinfo: I have verified that the jquery file exists at  HTML/jquery.js but despite this, Visual Studio 2008 issues a warning of file not found. Another .aspx page with the exact same path to the jquery file does not issue this warning.

UPDATE:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Manage/ConceptManager.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="ConceptManager.aspx.cs" Inherits="DynamicForm.Manage.ConceptManagerPage" %>

<%@ Register src="Controls/Element_MetadataEditor_FieldNode.ascx" tagname="Element_MetadataEditor_FieldNode" tagprefix="uc1" %>

<%@ Register src="Controls/Element_MetadataEditor_TemplateNode.ascx" tagname="Element_MetadataEditor_TemplateNode" tagprefix="uc3" %>

<%@ Register src="Controls/CategoryAttributes.ascx" tagname="CategoryAttributes" tagprefix="usercontrol" %>

<%@ Register Src="Controls/ConfirmDialog.ascx" TagName="DeleteConfirmDialog" TagPrefix="usercontrol" %>
<%@ Register Src="Controls/ConfirmDialog.ascx" TagName="ConfirmDialog" TagPrefix="usercontrol" %>
<%@ Register src="Controls/AddReferenceDialog.ascx" TagName="AddReferenceDialog" TagPrefix="usercontrol" %>
<%@ Register src="Controls/AddIncludeDialog.ascx" TagName="AddIncludeDialog" TagPrefix="usercontrol" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="ExtExtenders" Namespace="ExtExtenders" TagPrefix="ExtExt" %>

<asp:Content ID="ContentHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var mydomain = "mysite.com";
        var leavemessage = "Are you sure you wish to leave?";

        var filterMySitefunction = function(index) {
            return $(this).attr("href").indexOf(mydomain) > -1;
        }
        var filterOtherSitefunction = function(index) {
            return $(this).attr("href").indexOf(mydomain) == -1;
        }
        $("a").filter(filterMySitefunction).click(function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() { };
        });
        $("a").filter(filterOtherSitefunction).click(function() {
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                return leavemessage;
            };
        });
    });                                       
</script>  
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm utterly baffled. No offense to Peeter above, but that seems like an overly complicated solution when the same can be achieved by doing something like

```
$(function($){
    $('a').not('[href*="mydomain.com"]')
          .click(function(e){
              // visiting some other domain!
          });
});
```

The excellent [jQuery: In Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988355) book also suggests simply checking for `a[href^="http://"]` to check for external links, and this is how I'd insist in doing it.

Personally (and because I'm a bit paranoid with this particular bit), I slap the two together as a sort of a catch-all (just in case someone or *something* throws in an internal absolute URL).

```
$('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href*="mydomain.com"]')
                       .click(function(e){
                           // visiting some other domain!
                       });
```

Comment: Doesn't your solution (and Peeter's) assume that internal links are fully qualified URLs, including the domain name, instead of relative hrefs like `/some_other_page.html`? The selector you cite from the book seems like the better option, if paired with the "not my own domain" check.

Comment: @nrabinowitz ~ I completely agree; the code I cited above was merely how I'd simplify @Peeter's solution. In a business environment, I actually use the `http://` check I also cited, and I suggest using that instead. Let me edit my answer to make that clearer. Good catch. +1

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(document).ready(function(){

    var mydomain = "mysite.com";
    var leavemessage = "Are you sure you wish to leave?";

    var filterMySitefunction = function(index) {
        return $(this).attr("href").indexOf(mydomain) > -1;
    }
    var filterOtherSitefunction = function(index) {
        return $(this).attr("href").indexOf(mydomain) == -1;
    }
    $("a").filter(filterMySitefunction).click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){};
    });
    $("a").filter(filterOtherSitefunction).click(function() {
        window.onbeforeunload = function(){
            return leavemessage;
        };
    });
});                                       
</script>  

<a href="mysite.com">Omg</a>
<a href="othersite.com">Omg</a>
```

### Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/K8cuE/

Comment: Thanks, but does this solution mean I have to specify all my internal links?

Comment: Just change mysite.com to your actual domain name. This example won't prompt the user if they navigate to sites that are on the same domain.

Comment: Ah, I understand, thanks! This should be sufficient to my requirements although it still bugs me that the jquery-solution just wont work.

Comment: Oh uhm, as you can probably tell I'm not completely comfortable with the technology yet. I guess I thought that this solution was pure javascript.

Comment: I added another example that's easier to modify.

Comment: Hmm, it seems as if no other methods than the window.unbeforeload are being run at all, tried both your solutions and only the first one had any response at all. Any ideas on what could cause that ? Could it have something to do with the page having Ajaxcomponents with buttons that behave differently or something along those lines?

Comment: Yes, I added src="HTML/jquery.js" to the script-header.

Comment: Do you have any exceptions in the console? Can you provide the link to your site?

Comment: Do you use multiple js frameworks? JQuery and Prototype or something?

Comment: Never heard of Prototype :) This is interesting though: I made a test-project to try out a solution before, which works perfectly when run on both Chrome and IE. But when pasting in the sourcecode in Jsfiddle, it doesn't work as expected - it doesn't run the jquery-code when pressing on a link. See http://jsfiddle.net/haBjK/

Comment: You're refrencing a script from your HDD. <script type="text/javascript" src="C:\Users\Soroush\jquery.js"></script>. Works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/peeter/haBjK/2/

Comment: I have gotten so far as to understand that $(document).ready/live(function() { } is what is not working, anything placed inside this method is simply not called. It remains to be found out why.

Comment: I've updated the main answer again, please just copy/paste it and let me know what happens.

Comment: Updated the original post with the new code. I left the url to mysite.com just to get a reaction but nothing happened. I got no interesting output but one peculiar warning: Warning 53 Error updating JScript IntelliSense: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Temporary Internet Files\Content.IE5\VM5LJTB9\jquery.min-fds90[2]..js: Object doesn't support this property or method @ 15:15372 C:\path\ConceptManager.aspx 1 1 DynamicForm

Comment: Download firefox and install firebug and see what errors you actually get in your console.

Comment: Debugged a bit now, and I could see no error output in the console. I put breakpoints on the $("a").filter(filterMySitefunction).click(function() method, but when clicking a link, the code did stop at the breakpoint, but wouldn\t go INTO the method for some reason. This applies to both filterMySite and filterOtherSite.

Comment: Unless you replicate your problem on jsfiddle or link me to the actual site causing the error I cannot help you any further. The code I provided works fine, so it's probably your sites javascript.

Comment: I understand, thanks alot anyhow! I'd ofcourse provide you with the site if I could, but it's not publicly online.

Comment: Is it possible to fetch a specific ID of a clicked component? If so, one could pretty easily get around all this by just placing something an if-clause around the return statement, like if($(this).attr("id") == ext-gen1 ) where I know that ext-gen1 is the id shown when exiting the application, and where the buttons have other id's set automaticly. Running this mentioned code now generates "ext-gen1" despite where I click, so I guess there must be some other code to get the clicked elements attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$(document).live('click',function() {
     $("a").click(function() {
         alert("Hello world!");
     });
 });
```

to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("a").click(function() {
         alert("Hello world!");
     });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunatly it made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to the live click.

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click(function() {
         alert("Hello world!");
     });
});
```

Comment: Didn't change the outcome unfortunatly.